# Smart contract verification

Tags: contract-development, tokens, contract-deployment

I want to create a token using smart contract. Before deploying it on the blockchain, do I have to get the smart contract verified from the third party or can I directly deploy the contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy it directly, no one is in charge of officially verifying contracts in the network. However, your users will be reassured of your seriousness if you share the actual code of your contract. To be sure that the code you posted as "`your contract code" is the same as the actual contract in the network, you could verify it, this can be done using [Etherscan code source verification](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract).

Hope this helps